# SWR Keep getting the same data through the loop

Tags: reactjs, next.js, fetch, swr

I have home component  and i passing props into Product card component

```
                {products.map((product: ProductListStoreType) => (
                    <ProductCard
                        key={product.slug}
                        product={product}
                        category={product.category}
                    />
                ))}
            </div>
```

Category is just string  _id from mongo db

and inside the product card

```
export default function ProductCard({ product, category }: ProductCardProps) {
    const getCategory = async () => {
        const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/category/${category}`);
        return data.name;
    };
    const { data } = useSWR('/api/category', getCategory);
    console.log(data);
```

The problem is SWR returns the same data for every loop.  the id category is unique because it is from the _id mongo DB. but SWR keeps returning the same data which is from the category  _id from the  first loop

[awlays return the first data for every map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTmDf.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter of `useSWR` is a unique `key` identifying the request. Since the key you are passing does not change (it's always `'/api/category'`), the data is not refreshed.

The `key` will be as the first argument to your `fetcher`, see [the docs on arguments](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/arguments).

With these two things in mind, you could do something like this:

```
const getCategory = async (path) => {
    const { data } = await axios.get(path);
    return data.name;
};

export default function ProductCard({ product, category }: ProductCardProps) {
    const { data } = useSWR(`/api/category/${category}`, getCategory);
```